# Export PyTorch model to ONNX with fixed batch size

Tags: python, pytorch, onnx

I am trying to export a PyTorch model to ONNX as follows:

```py
import torch
from transformers import BertModel
from tvm import relay
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(1000000)

bert = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
embedding_dim = bert.config.to_dict()['max_position_embeddings']

device = "cuda"

HIDDEN_DIM = 256
OUTPUT_DIM = 1
N_LAYERS = 2
DROPOUT = 0

bert = model.BERTGRUSentiment(bert, HIDDEN_DIM, OUTPUT_DIM, N_LAYERS, DROPOUT)
bert.eval()
bert.to(device)

print(f"cuda: {next(bert.parameters()).is_cuda}")
print(f"training: {bert.training}")

input_name = "text"
input_shape = [embedding_dim]

example = model.preprocess(model.tokenizer, "it was ok").unsqueeze(0)

print(example)

torch.onnx.export(bert, example, "model.onnx", export_params=True, opset_version=10, do_constant_folding=True, input_names = ['text'], output_names = ['output'])
```

However, when I try this, I get the following warning:

`UserWarning: Exporting a model to ONNX with a batch_size other than 1, with a variable length with GRU can cause an error when running the ONNX model with a different batch size. Make sure to save the model with a batch size of 1, or define the initial states (h0/c0) as inputs of the model.`

Is there a way to fix the batch size of the model?

Comment: What do you mean by "fix"? You are exporting the model with a batch size of 1, so there is no need to worry about the warning in this case.